# How to add <br /> after Artikler with jquery

Tags: jquery

The following source is created dynamically.

I'd like to add

```
    <br /> 
after Artikler, to become 
    Artikler<br />.
```

Source

```
<div id="shopping">
    <p><!--TEXT:--> <A HREF="cart-8.asp" CLASS="longsum">7&nbsp;Artikler, verdi:&nbsp;10 199,00</A></p>
    </div>
```

I think I need to use

```
.after('<br />');
```

but I am not sure how to get Artikler.

7  will be changed dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jQuery DOM manipulation functions (such as `after()`) work specifically on DOM elements, and in this case your entire block of text is a single element.

A better approach is to get the text out of the element:

```
var text = $("a.longsum").html();
```

Then do your string replace:

```
text = text.replace("Artikler", "Artikler<br />");
```

and put the result back into the element:

```
$("a.longsum").html(text);
```

Comment: Note that if you want to add a line break after each occurrence of `Artikler`, you'll have to use `text = text.replace(/Artikler/g, 'Artikler<br />');`.

Answer (score 0):

```
"7&nbsp;Artikler, verdi:&nbsp;10 199,00".replace("Artikler", "Artikler<br />");
```

this should do the thing if i got you correctly